# Communication protocol being used: TCP/IP

Tags: python-3.x, database, db2, robotframework

```
import ibm_db

def db22():
 connection=ibm_db.connect("DATABASE=XXXXX;HOSTNAME=xxxx;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=XXXXXX;PWD=xxxxx", '','')

 coursor = connection.cursor()
 sql = 'select * from wwwcllogin where lower(email) = 
 lower(test274225@gmail.com)'
 coursor.execute(sql)
 result = coursor.fetchall()
 for x in result:
   print(x)
 connection.close()
```

This is the error I am getting:

error : [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "100.64.1.105".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001
 SQLCODE=-30081

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: May I know how can I fix this error?

Comment: Based on the error message, there is a TCP/IP level error when use "recv".  So it may be suggested to check TCP/IP network related things between the client application machine and IP address 100.64.1.105 machine to see if there any unexpected condition or not.  To narrow down the issue, try to use a simple select statement which returns only some rows.

Answer (score 0):

[`SQL30081N` / `-30081`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc-gentopic27.html#sql30081n) is some sort of network issue. Usually this means the server is not online, or some sort of firewall is blocking access.

You can see various troubleshooting suggestions in the manual page I linked above.